# Algorithm Recursion Sorting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion, arraylist

I have an algorithm :

```
ALGORITHM F_min1(A[0..n-1])
//Input: An array A[0..n-1] of real numbers
If n = 1
    return A[0]
else
    temp ← F_minl(A[0..n-2])
    If temp ≤ A[n-1]
        return temp
    else
        return A[n-1]
```

I suspect it sorts the array, but I don't know how exactly. I think it looks at the minimum element of the array except the last, compares them, and prints the greater one.

Answer (score 0):

Almost; it returns the *lesser*, not the greater.
Also, it doesn't sort the array at all: it merely returns the smallest element.

In words, this reads something like:

```
If there is only one element, it must be the right one -- return it.
Otherwise,
    recur: find the smallest element in all but the last one.
    compare the last element to that minimum; return the smaller one.
```

When you return all the way to the initial call, you have the smallest element of the array.

Comment: Does it return only one element ? For example if the array is 3 7 5 2 1. It looks at 3 7 5 2 and then compares 2 with 1 and prints 1. After that it looks 3 7 5 and compares 3 with 2 and prints 2.So and so forth ?

Comment: Right: this returns only the least element.  It never alters the original list, nor does it construct a new list to return.